# Is it really reasonable to write tests at the early stage?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

I used to write the tests while developing my software, but I stopped it because I noticed that, almost always, the first api and structures I thought great turn out to be clumsy after some progress. I would need to rewrite the entire main program *and* the entire test every time.

I believe this situation is common in reality. So my questions are:

- Is it **really** common to write tests at first, like so said in TDD? I'm just an amateur programmer so I don't know the real development world.
- If so, do people rewrite the tests again (and again) when they revamp the software api/structure? (unless they're smart enough to think up the best one at first, unlike me.)

Comment: They turn out to be lame... in what way ?

Comment: "clumsy" was more suitable... edited. One common situation for me is that some functions are inevitably interrelated although the planned structure assumed that they would be completely independent.

Comment: But does that change the externally visible behavior of these functions ? Do clients that call them have to change after you realized this, and if so, in what way ? Can you provide an example ?

Comment: Well, for example, my website (client, kind of) had to display only a little data collected from some other websites. Later, I noticed that it will be better to display more, but my scraping code couldn't collect those and the code must be revamped completely. I had no tests, and I was relieved I didn't take my time for writing tests.

Comment: I think you're missing an abstraction somewhere. Changing the way you scrape the data shouldn't change the external behavior of your API and thus your tests. (see my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of anyone who recommends TDD when you don't know what you're building yet. Unless you've created a very similar system before, then you prototype first, without TDD. There is a very real danger, however, of ending up putting the prototype into production without ever bringing the TDD process into play.

Some common ways of doin' it right are…

A. Throw the prototype away, and start over using TDD (can still borrow some code almost verbatim from the prototype, just re-implement following the actual TDD cycle).

B. Retrofit unit tests into the prototype, and then proceed with red, green, refactor from there.

Comment: I TDD'd on a project recently from scratch (still am) I am not a purist but I do have a fairly good idea of how to write testable code. It is something that comes with experience.

Comment: If you don't know what you are building, why are you building it?

Comment: Gradually realize that the car the customer is asking to have designed should be fast exciting, maneuverable, and only require space for between 0 and 1 passengers. In other words, it turns out the customer is looking for a motorcycle.

Comment: But from the start you know you are building a vehicle, and unlike a physical item changing from "4 wheels to 2" is quite cheap and the tests (turns left, goes left) still largely count.

Comment: This is actually a very deep and broad subject. Very early in a project, when even a good basic shape of the architecture is not yet known, TDD definitely can slow things down. Prototypes should be cheap enough to make that they're cheap enough to throw away without stress. Certainly, not every new app has that many unknowns, but many do. To continue the car vs motorcycle analogy, cars have axles, differentials, interiors, etc. Shouldn't invest too much time on those details early just product is supposedly a car. Likewise, don't want to spend too much time on 2-cycle engine design for a car.

Comment: /Prototypes should be cheap enough to make that they're cheap enough to throw away without stress./ This I agree with. To continue with the car/bike analogy your prototypes should be drawn pictures and later 3D printed models. If after a that you don't know if it is a car or a bike I think you have something seriously wrong. But they are not prototypes that can be evolved into the final product.

Answer (score 2):

> but I stopped it because I noticed that, almost always, the first api and structures I thought great turn out to be clumsy after some progress

Test driven development should help you with the design. An API that is "clumsy" will seam clumsy as you write your tests for it.

> Is it really common to write tests at first, like so said in TDD?

Depends on the developers. I use Test driven development for 99% of what I write. It aids in the design of the APIs and applications I write.

> If so, do people rewrite the tests again (and again) when they revamp the software api/structure?

Depends on the level of the tests. Hopefully during a big refactor (that is when you rewrite a chunk of code) you have some tests at the to cover the work you are about to do. Some unit tests will be thrown away but integration and functional tests will be very important. They are what tells you that nothing has been broken.

You may have noticed I've made a point of writing test driven development and not "TDD". Test driven development is not simply "writing tests first", it is allowing the tests to drive the development cycle. The design of your API will be strongly effected by the tests that you write (contrived example, that singleton or service locator will be replaced with IoC). Writing good APIs takes practice and learning to listen to the tools you have at your disposal.

Answer (score 0):

Purists say yes but in practice it works out a little different. Sometimes I write a half dozen tests and then write the code that passes them. Other times I will write several functions before writing the tests because those functions are not to be used in isolation or testing will be hard.

And yes, you may find you need to rewrite tests as API change.

And to the purists, even they will admit that some tests are better than none.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it really reasonable to write tests at the early stage?

- No if you are writing [top-down-design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-down_and_bottom-up_design) high level [integrationtests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) that require a real database or internetconnection to an other website to work
- yes if you are implementing [bottom-up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-down_and_bottom-up_design) with [unittesting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) (=testing a module in isolation)

The higher the "level" the more difficuilt the unittesting becomes because you have to introduce more mocking/abstraction.

In my opinion the architectual benefits of tdd only apply when combined with unittesting because this drives the [Separation_of_concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

When i started tdd i had to rewrite many tests when changing the api/architecture. With grown experience today there are only a few cases where this is neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a first layer of tests that verifies the externally visible behavior of your API regardless of its internals.

Updating this kind of tests when a new functional requirement emerges is not a problem. In the example you mention, it would be easy to adjust to new websites being scraped - you would just add new assertions to the tests to account for the new data fetched.

The fact that *"the scraping code had to be revamped entirely"* shouldn't affect the structure of these higher level tests, because from the outside, the API should be consumed exactly the same way as before.

If such a low-level technical detail does affect your high level tests, you're probably missing an abstraction that describes **what** data you get but hides the details of **how** it is retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

Writing tests before you write the actual code would mean you know how your application will be designed. This is rarely the case.

As a matter of fact I for example start writing everything in a single file. It might have a few hundereds or more lines. This way I can easily and quickly redesign the api. Later when I decide I like it and that it's good I start refactoring it by putting everything in meaningfull namespaces and separate files.

When this is done I start writing tests to verify everything works fine and to find bugs.

TDD is just a myth. It is not possible to write tests first and the code later especially if you are at the beginning.

You always have to keep in mind the KISS rule. If you need some crazy stuff to test you own code like fakes or mocks you already failed it.